# XSS- Cross-Site Scripting: DOM issue

Tags: dom, xss, fortify

Fortify scan caught this below error as critical. can some please help ?

switchcontent.loadpage=function(page_request, header){
    var innercontent=document.getElementById(header.id.replace("-title", "")) //Reference content container for this header
    innercontent.innerHTML=switchcontent_ajax_msg //Display "fetching page message"
    if (page_request.readyState == 4 && (page_request.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1)){
        **innercontent.innerHTML=page_request.responseText**
        header.ajaxstatus="loaded"
    }
}

what change would be needed to fix this code for avoiding XSS ? Any help is greatly appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the responseText are HTML tags inserted or is it just text you want to insert/change? s a rule of thumb always sanitize/encode all user input and output that is generated from user input. If it's only text that you're inserting use `document.createTextNode` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718091/alternative-for-innerhtml)) and append the text to the element's needed (always encoded also), I would recomend using jQuery .text() as with pure javascript it's kind of cumbersome. If it's HTML that is needed to be inserted be sure it's not user input as this is a vulnerability. If the text needs to be from a user use a whitelist to check that the user is only writing tags that you are expecting for example `<p></p>`.

Fortify treats this as a vulnerability because if a user sends in the responseText `<script>alert('XSS')</script>` the page will render this as HTML and the script will be executed if you encode this it would just appear as text and not be executed, not only scripts can be executed but HTML will be rendered also and deform your page. You can read more in: [OWASP DOM Prevention Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

Points:

1: ALWAYS ENCODE USER INPUT!

2: If it's just text create text nodes and append them to the element to make this easier use jQuery if possible function `.text()` not `.html()` as the `.htlm()` function will render the HTML.

3: If it's user generated HTML sanitize malicious tags agains a WHITELIST you can do blacklist but blacklists are not that safe as there are always tags you could forget to check against.

4: If the HTML is server generated and has not user input you should be fine.

5: Know that Fortify is just a scanning tool and it has false positives, so if you have the right countermeasures you should be XSS free.

Whitelisting: Checking agains a list of available tags. Only letting tags that you know the user can use like `<p></p><br/>`.

Blacklisting: Checking against a list of "not welcome" tags. This means having a list with tags you don't want to let the user use.