# A substitute for inner.HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a project for my university and the teachers have forbidden the use of inner.HTML for some reason.
I tried using the solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718091/alternative-for-innerhtml) question, but it isn't doing anything for me.

Is there a way to change text within an HTML page through DOM manipulation without using inner.HTML?

Edit: Just like the guy in the ther question, I don't want to just add text but rather change text that is already on the page.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. If you only want to change some text content, `innerText` would be enough to do it. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030742/difference-between-innertext-innerhtml-and-value)

Answer (score -1):

You could use a Javascript library for this, such as Knockout or React.

The example from Knockout's page would work great(https://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html):

```
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
<h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>!</h2>
```

```
// Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
    this.lastName = ko.observable(last);
 
    this.fullName = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        // Knockout tracks dependencies automatically. It knows that fullName depends on firstName and lastName, because these get called when evaluating fullName.
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);
};
 
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth")); // This makes Knockout get to work
```