# How to query and update the DOM with yew?

Tags: reactjs, rust, yew, web-sys

Is there any way to make DOM action via `use_node_ref`? or alternatively, how to do `document.query_selector()` in Rust using yew?

```rust
use web_sys::HtmlInputElement;
use yew::{
    function_component, functional::*, html,
    NodeRef, Html
};

#[function_component(UseRef)]
pub fn ref_hook() -> Html {
    let input_ref = use_node_ref();
    let all_editables =  input_ref.query_selector("[contenteditable]")
    web_sys::console::(all_editables)

    html! {
        <div>
            <input ref={input_ref} type="number" />
        </div>
    }
}
```

**Goal:** I have a rich text editor app. And I have a minified html in form of string like this `<h1> this is title</h1><p>hello world</>` and I need to get the DOM and change the `innerHTML` to set it to this value.

**Goal2:** I will also need to update the `innerHtml` as the user write things in the `contenteditable` elements. Fore example when the user type `@john smith` I will make a create an `<a>` element with `href` the have the link to `John smith`'s profile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many things to tackle with your question.

### #1 Do not set inner html

More to read about this in [Alternative for innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/718091/11035017)

But instead create text nodes.
So using web-sys you would do something like:

```rust
let txtNode: Node = window()
    .unwrap_throw()
    .document()
    .unwrap_throw()
    .create_text_node("Hello")
    .dyn_into()
    .unwrap_throw();

myDomElement.append_hild(&txtNode).unwrap_throw();
```

### #2 How to query data from an input

There are many ways to do this so ill just show you one of them -
controlled input

core idea is keep your input value in `use_state` and sync it with the input element using `value` and `oninput` attributes.

```rust
#[function_component(ControlledInputComponent)]
pub fn controlled_input_component() -> Html {
    let my_text_handle = use_state(|| "".to_string());
    let my_text = (*my_text_handle).clone();
    
    let handle_input = Callback::from(move |input_event: InputEvent| {
        let event: Event = input_event.dyn_into().unwrap_throw();
        let input_elem: HTMLInputElement = event.target().unwrap_throw().dyn_into().unwrap_throw();
        let value = input_elem.value();
        my_text_handle.set(value); // update as user types
        
    });

    html! {
        <div>
            <input type="text" value={my_text} oninput={handle_input} />
        </div>
    }
}
```

### #3 Update DOM

**External to yew as you should generally avoid updating DOM that is controlled by yew

You can then use `use_effec_with_deps` to react to your input changing and update your external preview there

```rust
let my_text_handle = use_state(|| "".to_string());
let my_text = (*my_text_handle).clone();

use_effect_with_deps(move |my_text| {
    // run all the code from my tip #1 like:
    // myDomElement.append_hild(&txtNode).unwrap_throw();
    ||{}
}, my_text);
```